# Error in xcode after adding adWhirl/adMod SDK

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, clang

I am compiling xcode cocos2d project after including adWhirl/adMod SDK. but I am getting below error when I don't any clue. Anyone saw similar error?

duplicate symbol _main in:
    /Users/rameshjangama/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Smarty_SG-bevjqrzchdoqlherhrgqjvyiscvk/Build/Intermediates/Smarty SG.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Smarty SG.build/Objects-normal/i386/main-1C64DB92F3446C47.o
    /Users/rameshjangama/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Smarty_SG-bevjqrzchdoqlherhrgqjvyiscvk/Build/Intermediates/Smarty SG.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Smarty SG.build/Objects-normal/i386/main-ED4E1B3DCBD8732E.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_RootViewController in:
    /Users/rameshjangama/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Smarty_SG-bevjqrzchdoqlherhrgqjvyiscvk/Build/Intermediates/Smarty SG.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Smarty SG.build/Objects-normal/i386/RootViewController-214B0A37FE12675B.o
    /Users/rameshjangama/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Smarty_SG-bevjqrzchdoqlherhrgqjvyiscvk/Build/Intermediates/Smarty SG.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Smarty SG.build/Objects-normal/i386/RootViewController-6E15F3A1FAEF641D.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_RootViewController in:
    /Users/rameshjangama/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Smarty_SG-bevjqrzchdoqlherhrgqjvyiscvk/Build/Intermediates/Smarty SG.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Smarty SG.build/Objects-normal/i386/RootViewController-214B0A37FE12675B.o
    /Users/rameshjangama/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Smarty_SG-bevjqrzchdoqlherhrgqjvyiscvk/Build/Intermediates/Smarty SG.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Smarty SG.build/Objects-normal/i386/RootViewController-6E15F3A1FAEF641D.o
ld: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've added to the project twice adWhirl / adMod SDK. Check carefully all the branches of your project in the left pane.

Also, do clean-up project with the help of the following: the top menu -> Product -> Clean. After that, the same steps, but before this, press and hold Alt.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, i dragged entine adMob folder to my project folder in xcode.  Butg in that adMob folder another sample example xcode project exists which caused that 'main' conflicts. I removed sample appllication from adMob and its recompiled and worked fine. Infog, thats a lot for your reply.